# Redirect stderr to stdout on exec-ed process from python?

Tags: python, linux, redirect, file-descriptor

In a bash script, I can write:

```
exec 2>&1
exec someprog
```

And the stderr output of `someprog` would be redirected to stdout.

Is there any way to do a similar thing using python's [`os.exec*`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.execl) functions?

This doesn't have to be portable, just work on Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`os.dup2(1, 2)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.dup2)

#### Illuminating examples

Let's execute `/bin/ls` with a bogus argument so that it complains to stderr.

```
$ python -c "import os; os.execl('/bin/ls', '', 'ffweew')" 1>/dev/null
: ffweew: No such file or directory
$ python -c "import os; os.execl('/bin/ls', '', 'ffweew')" 2>/dev/null
$ python -c "import os; os.dup2(1, 2); os.execl('/bin/ls', '', 'ffweew')" 1>/dev/null
$ python -c "import os; os.dup2(1, 2); os.execl('/bin/ls', '', 'ffweew')" 2>/dev/null
: ffweew: No such file or directory
$
```

First two invocations prove that `ls` does not write to stdout, and writes the error message to stderr.

In the 3rd and the 4th invocation, the Python program duplicates file descriptor 1 as file descriptor 2, achieving the desired effect.